# How do I use "JSXInternal" type in deno fresh?

Tags: deno, preact, freshjs

I'm trying to create a HOC that returns a preact component, and I don't have access to the "JSXInternal" type, how can I access it?

Answer (score 1):

```
import type { JSX } from "preact";

function Hyper (Component: (props: PageProps) => JSX.Element): (props: PageProps) => JSX.Element {
  return (props: PageProps) => {
    return <Component {...props}/>
  }
}
```